# Cannot retrieve value for specified key from Config file

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to retrieve a specified key from my configuration file, but when I output the variable that holds the value associated with the key, I'm not getting errors but nothing is being displayed to the console. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm trying to get the value from the key, not fix the warning.

Code for config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="TITLE" value="MR"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code in main:

```
 Dim sAttr As String

    sAttr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TITLE")

    Console.WriteLine(sAttr)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: The code and the config file look correct, so maybe the application isn't seeing the configuration file. With a console program like this, the config file in the project is named app.config, but when the project is built app.config goes into the bin folder and its root name is changed to the DLL name. So if you did a debug build, look for the config file in <project-root>/bin/debug. See if that has the "TITLE" value.

Comment: Hi @EdGibbs, thank you for the reply. There is no TITLE value in the config file.

Comment: That last question was different... I was asking how to get rid of the warning...

Comment: Therefore, how is it a duplicate? @zaggler

Comment: if there is no title value in the build, add it to the debug app.config file. then run the program.

Comment: Ok, will try this out.

Comment: did it work. If it did, I think you will need to delete the app.config file and read it.

Comment: Okay, so when I put <add key ="TITLE" value="Mr"/> in the app.config file in the solution explorer, when I run the program, I get an error "Configuration system failed to initialize".

Comment: Try deleting your app file because your code to get the value is correct. Instead of manually adding it, try right clicking on the project | select Properties | select Settings      ---- Under the value column type something in. Visual Studios will create the app.config file for you. Then add the above code and try it.

Comment: Thank you @codeMonger123, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else Reading this:

Try deleting your app file because your code to get the value is correct. Instead of manually adding it, try right clicking on the project | select Properties | select Settings ---- Under the value column type something in. Visual Studios will create the app.config file for you. Then add the above code and try it.

After the app file is created you will then need to/should delete what Visual basics put in your app file under settings.